# GPDR Google analytics async script is still setting cookie while script is not present anymore in page source code

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-analytics

I'm trying to normalize a website with U.E GPDR reglementation.

We are working on Symfony4/Twig.

I set up a bundle which handle user's choices for cookies.

It work with a GET URL, where I remove unwanted cookies then redirect to the request header's referrer.

And a twig function that will control user consent before to put Google Analytics scripts while rendering the page.

The problem is that one of the google analytics cookies come back after being removed, while in source page, his script is not present anymore. If I manually remove the cookie, then refresh the page, the cookie won't come back.

It is not a problem with the condition because the script is not present in page's source code and because the other google analytics cookies are not coming back.

It occurs with a Google Analytics async script, I suspect a cache problem but I don't understand what is the problem, if some one have an idea, it could be helpful!

the GET URL:

```
/**
 * @Route("make-the-pie/{action}", options={"expose"=true}, methods={"GET"}, name="make_the_pie")
 */
public function makeThePieAction(Request $request, int $action = self::DENY_ALL)
{
    ...
    $response = new RedirectResponse($request->headers->get('referer'));

    switch ($action) {
        case self::DENY_ALL:
            ...
            $this->clearUserCookies($request, $response);
            break;
        ...        
    }
    ...
    return $response;
}
```

The clearUserCookies function (the name of concerned cookie start by '_ga_', the 'setCookie' with expired value is present in response header)

```
    private function clearUserCookies(Request $request, Response $response, bool $clearAnalytics = true, bool $clearTiers = true)
    {
        $cookies = $request->cookies;
        $domain = $request->server->get('SERVER_NAME');
        $secure = ($request->server->get('REQUEST_SCHEME') === 'https') ? true : false;
        $lastMonth = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m") - 1, date("d"), date("Y"));
        $realDomain = explode('.', $domain);
        $realDomain = '.' . $realDomain[1] . '.' . $realDomain[2];

        foreach ($cookies as $cookieName => $cookieValue) {
            if ($clearAnalytics && preg_match('/^(_g|_hj)/', $cookieName)) {
                $removeCookie = new Cookie($cookieName, "deleted", $lastMonth, '/', $realDomain, $secure, true, true);
                $response->headers->setCookie($removeCookie);
            }
            ...
        }
    }
```

In front, the code where I set the Google script, with other Google scripts that are not triggered (so the condition is working):

```
{% if tarteAuxPommes(app.request.cookies, 'analytics') %}
    <!-- Problematic script -->

    <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"></script>
    
    <!-- Not problematic script -->

    <script>
      window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
      function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
      gtag('js', new Date());
      gtag('config', 'xxxxxxxxxxxx');
    </script>       
{% endif %}
```

Page source code when we do accept Google Analytics (don't pay attention to the console.log, it was a test but it's not working anyway):

[image]

Page source code direct after redirect, when we have denied google analytics cookies (script async is not present but the cookie is still coming back after the loading of the page):

[image]

######### UPDATE QUICK FIX #########

Quick fix is to manually remove the cookie at page load but I shouldn't have to do this:

```
{% if tarteAuxPommes(app.request.cookies, 'analytics') %}
   <-- see code below -->
{% else %}
    <script type='text/javascript'>
      let cookies = document.cookie.split('; ');
      cookies.forEach(cookie => {
        let cookieParams = cookie.split('=');
        if (cookieParams[0].match(/_g|_hj/)) {
          let cookie = `${cookieParams[0]}=deleted;path=/;domain=${document.domain.split('www')[1]};expires=${new Date(Date.now() - 1000).toUTCString()}`;
          document.cookie = cookie;
         }
       })
    </script>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Now I suspect google analytics to set the cookie just before the redirection (on beforeunload), because, on my browser when I received the redirect response, all my ga cookies were removed (even the problematic one), then I was redirected and the cookie was back again (without google analytic script in source code)